# Vue.js / How to access the function in another component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, components

I just started learning Vue.js. I need to call the function in another component in my project. When I add new data to the table with `createAnnouncement.vue`, I want to go into `announcement.vue` and call the `queryAnnouncement` function. How can I do that? I would appreciate if you could help, please explain with a sample. Or edit my codes.

**`Announcement.Vue`** template:

```
    <template>
           // more div or not important template code
                <div class="dataTables_filter" style="margin-bottom:10px">
                    <label>
                        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Search" aria-controls="m_table_1" type="search" v-model="searchField" @change="filter()">
                    </label>
                    <a style="float:right" href="#" data-target="#create-announcement-modal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <i class="">Add</i>&nbsp;
                    </a>
                </div>

         // more div or not important template code
</template>
```

**`Announcement.Vue`** Script Code:

```
<script>
import toastr from "toastr";
export default {
    name: 'announcement',
    data() {
        return {
            announcements: [],
            searchField: "",
            deleteCsrfToken: this.$root.csrfTokens["deleteAnnouncement"]
        }
    },
    beforeMount: async function () {
        await this.queryAnnouncements();
    },
    methods: {
        filter: async function () {
            await this.queryAnnouncements(this.searchField);
        },
        queryAnnouncements: async function (filter, pageSize, pageIndex, sortBy, sortType) {
            var data = {
                "query[general-filter]": filter,
                "pagination[perpage]": !!pageSize ? pageSize : 10,
                "pagination[page]": !!pageIndex ? pageIndex : 1,
                "sort[field]": sortType,
                "sort[sort]": !!sortBy ? sortBy : "asc"
            };
            let response = await axios
                .get("/Announcement/QueryAnnouncements", { params: data })
            this.announcements = response.data.data;
        }, 
    }
}
```

**`createAnnouncement.vue`** code:

```
  <template>
     <button @click="createAnnouncement()" v-bind:disabled="contentDetail === ''" class="btn btn-success">
    Save</button>

    //not important template codes
    <template>
    <script>
    import toastr from "toastr";
    export default {
        name: 'create-announcement',
        data() {
            return {
                contentDetail: "",
                createCsrfToken: this.$root.csrfTokens["createAnnouncement"],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            createAnnouncement: async function () {
                var self = this;
                var data = {
                    content: this.contentDetail,
                };
                let response = await axios
                    .post("/Announcement/createAnnouncement",
                        data,
                        {
                            headers: {
                                RequestVerificationToken: self.createCsrfToken
                            }
                    })
                if (response.status == 200) {
                    $("#create-announcement-modal .close").click()
                    $("#create-announcement-form").trigger('reset');
                    toastr["success"]("Kayıt başarıyla eklendi!", "Başarılı!");
                    self.contentDetail = "";
                }
                else {
                    toastr["warning"]("Hata", "Kayıt Eklenemedi.");
                }

            }
        },

    }
</script>
```

Please show with sample or arrangement, my english is not very good. Thanks.

Comment: please follow this article https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860

Comment: How do I run the function after adding an announcement? Please show with sample @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: you want when you add an announcement in `createAnnouncement` component to call `queryAnnouncements`?

Comment: Yes! @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: So did  you followed the article in the given link above?

Comment: Yes bu I can't listen my add event. @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: i'm not familiar with async and await, for that reason i hesitate to post an answer to explain how to use event bus

Comment: Does createAnnouncement.vue have a template, need to see this to assist better.